# Issue in authentication in firebase cloud firestore at user level

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am analysing the get started guide for firebase cloud firestore. This is for an android app.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

I need to save and read the user data from every android device for backing up some data. The document for firebase cloud firestore shows the below code for accessing the data for all users. But I want to restrict the user data to be private so that it can be accessed only by the user who saved it. Please advice how to proceed with the access / authentication process.

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store in the document the uid of the user who saved the doc in a field called (for example) `createdBy` you can do as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid;
      allow write: .... 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do we still have visibility of data in console ?

Comment: I understand you answer.. Will it visible only to the creator ?

Comment: Yes indeed. If you store, at creation, the uid of the author in the field `createdBy`, the rule for `allow read` will restrict the read right only to the author. You may add a rule to avoid any modification to this field after creation (e.g. in an `allow update` rule). I'll suggest you watch the official video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw. If you think my answer was helpful you may upvote and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: One last Question.. 
Do we still have visibility of everyone data in console ? I prefer not to see users data in the console. will this be taken care by the code snippet you have provided ?

Comment: Security rules do not apply in the console. Anyone who had access to the console sees all the data. However accounts for accessing the console and user accounts are totally different.

Comment: So wont it be an security issue in developing android app. Basically I used Google drive for storing the data backup and it is totally secured and it is at the hands of user. Now the data is under our control. Can I view / edit / delete ? Wont it be an issue in android app as per google play ?

Comment: Not sure to 100% understand this new question. I would suggest you ask a new question with all the detail. If you think my answer to your initial question was helpful, please accept and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: what will be there in request.auth.uid ?  How to pass the values to request.auth.uid which sits in firebase

Comment: In `request.auth.uid` you will have the user ID, the one you see in the Firebase Console, in the Authentication part. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ for more details. Don't forget to upvote my answer, in addition to your acceptance! Thanks!