# What will be there in request.auth.uid?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am following the answers in the below link to use the "request.auth.uid" to filter the records for an user.
[Issue in authentication in firebase cloud firestore at user level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114230/issue-in-authentication-in-firebase-cloud-firestore-at-user-level)

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.createdBy ==     request.auth.uid;
      allow write: .... 
    }
  }
}
```

**Question**

1. what will be there in request.auth.uid ?
2. How to pass the values to request.auth.uid which sits in firebase

Comment: Don't post pictures of code (or other textual content) please. Instead post the code as text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it show up right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `request.auth.uid` will contain the UID of the user who has been authenticated with Firebase Authentication.
2. You don't pass values - they come directly from the client when Firebase Authentication is being used.  The user must be logged in, then the Firestore SDK will pass along the information.

Comment: What will be the user ID will it be the primary account's Email ID ? Will it be same for the user across devices ? If so how to get the UID ? I will save that in the field "createdBy"

Comment: Email addresses are not UIDs.  UIDs are unique IDs generated by Firebase Authentication.  It will be the for all logins from that account.

Comment: will that be same if the user logins from any other device ?

Comment: As I said **ALL** logins from that user will have the same user id.  Firebase Authentication would not be very useful if you had to make a new account for each device/browser.

Comment: I have this check "resource.data.createdBy ==     request.auth.uid" just to make sure the user is accessing only his data. please answer in that aspect. If this is not achievable. then I need to think a different approach that I have to decide based on your answer

Comment: Sure, you can do it.  This is a common thing.

Comment: 1. I understand the UID will be same if the user logs into the APP with the same primary gmail Account .
2. If I am going to use this check "resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid" at server side. How I need to get and populate the field "CreatedBy" in my client side ? In other words, How do I get the UID in client ?

I have to go for option 2 only when the answer for 1st question is yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186638/discussion-between-iappmaker-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566911/how-to-get-user-uid-from-firebase-on-android

Comment: Thats great link ! Thanks for that. 1 last confirmation .. will the UID be same if the user logs into the APP with the same primary gmail Account from any of the android device ?

Comment: As I said twice before, **ALL** logins from the same Firebase Authentication user account for your app will have the same UID.

Comment: Thank for your time and patience !

Answer (score 1):

- `request.auth.uid` represents the user ID for the Firebase User.
- As long as the user is logged in, Firestore automatically sends the values, there is no need for you to manually do that.

Comment: I planned to store the users email id by showing the account list. What will be the user ID will it be the primary account's Email ID ?

Answer (score 0):

For example: `{"uid": "iMuWxlrQYbQUoiAsH9N6bCPe37Hi", ..}`